# C# Server / Client Application for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, win-universal-app, uwp

I need to design a card game that will put on Windows Store and let people to 
download and play with each other OFFLINE.

1. They only need to be within the same wifi network for finding each other using UDP.
2. One player will be the host, while others will be the clients.
3. All clients will be send / receive data from the host

My question is,

1. does UWP support UDP communication, just like those Windows based client/server chat program, can discover the host using UDP.
2. each move during the game will need to send / receive from the host, what is the best way for the communication? In the past I will build a ServiceHost and use WCF for the communication between the host and clients. But seems UWP do not have such library.
3. I will store the game record, including each move of all players into host's device (which will upload to the cloud once there's internet access). Should I save that to SQLite or SQL Server Compact?

Thanks for any help.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does UWP support UDP communication, just like those Windows based
>   client/server chat program, can discover the host using UDP

UWP has DatagramSocket to support UDP communication. But to discover a host, you need to use the peer technology like Bluetooth and WiFi-direct. In UWP, you can use [PeerFinder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.aspx).

> Each move during the game will need to send / receive from the host,
>   what is the best way for the communication?

WCF is a little heavy, the raw data (bytes) communication should be enough if the logic is not very complex.

> I will store the game record, including each move of all players into
>   host's device (which will upload to the cloud once there's internet
>   access). Should I save that to SQLite or SQL Server Compact?

You can store the record in the SQLite or save the data in a plain text file. I recommend using the SQLite.

References:

[DatagramSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket)

Comment: Thank you for the information. It's very helpful. About "raw data communication", is it the "StreamSocket" which I found in the sample [StreamSocket Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket)? Most of our team member are web programmer, I've seen that Windows 10 IoT can embed the Node.js into the App, can my UWP also embed the Node.js? So that we can use HTTP get/post for data communication. Thanks.